# Can two different socket instances listen to same TCP port ( Port already in use )

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a TcpServer class that is responsible to, well, act like a tcp server. You can find the class below :

```
public class TcpServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private int locallyBoundPort;

    public TcpServer() {


    }

    public TcpServer(int locallyBoundPort) {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(locallyBoundPort);
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error at binding to port TCP : " + locallyBoundPort + "...cause : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        socket = null;

    }

    public void accept() {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error at accept : " + locallyBoundPort);
        }
    }



    public void send(Data data) throws IOException {
        if(socket != null) {

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(data);

        }
    }

    public Data receive() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        if(socket != null) {

                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                return (Data) in.readObject();

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean bind(int port) throws IOException {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.locallyBoundPort = port;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            OzumUtils.print("IOException in close, TcpServer");
        }

    }

    public int getLocallyBoundPort() {
        return locallyBoundPort;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
        return serverSocket;
    }
}
```

And I have a code piece that does this :

```
TcpServer tcpServer = new TcpServer(LocalPort);
while(1)
{
    tcpServer.accept();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new runnable(tcpServer));
    thread.start();
    tcpServer = new TcpServer(LocalPort);
}
```

However I am getting a port already in use error. I thought two different socket instances could listen to the same port as multiplexing allows two connections through the same port when the connector has different ip or port ?
What am I missing?

Comment: No, you can't use a port already in listening state. However any number of clients can connect to this same port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot bind two tcp server sockets to the same port. `reuseAddress` is really for client sockets, and it does not work the way you think it does ... and the way you are using it would not do anything at all either way (because you are setting it after binding).

You don't really need to bind twice to the same port either. Just remove this line  `tcpServer = new TcpServer(LocalPort);` from the bottom of your `while` loop, and you'll be all set.

The way this works is that you bind your server socket once and listen to the port. When a connection arrives, it forks a client socket for you to communicate with the client, and the original server socket continues to listen for more connections.

Basically, you need to remove the `socket` member (and any other state) from your `TcpServer`, and make the `accept` method return the accepted socket. Then make your `runnable` take that `socket` as a parameter instead of the `TcpServer`, and use that to serve the client connection. Then just keep calling `accept` in the loop, and forking threads for new connections same way you do know, except do not recreate the server every time.

Or, alternatively, remove the server socket and port from `TcpServer`, create the socket outside the loop, then `while(true)` call `accept` on it, create a new `TcpServer` with the returned client socket, and use it in a thread to process the connection.

Do not forget to close client sockets after you are done with them.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your detailed response. Let me ask you one more thing to clarify. Are you saying that when a TCP socket accepts a connection, it can simultaneously accept other connectors, and keep communicating with previous connectors ? Ohhh, while I am writing this, I realized this is the reason a new socket is returned when ServerSocket accepts a connector. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use a port already in listening state. However any number of clients can connect to this same port. You don't need to listen to the port again, you just spawn a new thread to process the current connection and wait for a new one. For example, supposing you have a class `TcpConnectionHanlder` that implements `Runnable` and takes the `Socket` as parameter, the loop would look like

```
while (true) { //while(1) is not valid Java syntax
    final Socket tcpSocket = tcpServer.accept(); // Get socket for incoming connection
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new TcpConnectionHanlder(tcpSocket)); // Create a thread for this socket/client connection
    thread.start(); // Launch the thread
    // tcpServer = new TcpServer(LocalPort); <- not needed, port still listening.
}
```

Then in your `TcpConnectionHanlder` instance you handle this particular client (socket).